# How to get all "outlet" about a certain vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a such graph:

```
g=Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
  4 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 9}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

If I want to get the vertex 4's *outlet* by `VertexOutComponent`

```
VertexOutComponent[g, 4]
```

> {4, 2, 6, 5, 3}

But we cannot from `4` to `3` by path $4\to2\to6\to5\to3$ obviously.Actually I want to get `{{4,2,3,5},{4,5},{4,6}}`.As this topological order,I name it a *outlet*.Or anther example frome the [documentation of VertexOutComponent](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexOutComponent.html):

[image]

Actually the `{{4,5,10},{4,9,10}}` is expected result.I have a custom funtion can do this:

```
FindAllOutlet[g_, v_] := 
 Module[{data}, 
  data = Catenate[FindPath[g, v, #, Infinity, All] & /@ VertexList[g]];
  Select[data, 
   VertexInDegree[
      SimpleGraph[
       RelationGraph[SubsetQ, EdgeList /@ PathGraph /@ data]], 
      EdgeList[PathGraph[#]]] == 0 &]]
```

[image]

```
FindAllOutlet[g, 4]
FindAllOutlet[g2, 4]
(* {{4, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}} *)
(* {{4, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 10}} *)
```

But I have to say this is a very violent and low efficience method.Cany any suggestion can give?

Comment: So what you want to call out-component is something else than what Mathematica calls out-component. I think nomenclature is irrelevant to the question.  What's important is to explain precisely the thing you want to compute.  A precise definition of your concept of "out-component" is missing.  The example is useful but not sufficient.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edited it.Is there any description is not suitable still?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a slightly quicker implementation of your `FindAllOutlet`. I presume you wish to follow every unique path from a vertex as far as it goes.

```
FindAllOutlet[g_, s_] :=
 Flatten[
  FindPath[g, s, #, \[Infinity], All] & /@ 
   Flatten[Position[VertexOutDegree[g], 0]],
  1]

FindAllOutlet[g, 4]

(*{{4, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}*)
```

Comment: Very smart adjustment.  :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be much faster than `FindAllOutlet` in Quantum_Oli's answer:

```
allPathsOut[g_, v_] :=  Module[{sink = Intersection[GraphComputation`SinkVertexList @ g, 
  VertexOutComponent[g, v]]}, Join @@ (FindPath[g, v, #, Infinity, All] & /@ sink)]
```

**Examples:**

```
allPathsOut[g, 4]
```

> {{4, 5}, {4, 2, 3, 5}, {4, 6}}

```
HighlightGraph[g, Style[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1], Opacity[1], 
  Arrowheads[.09],Thickness[.015], RandomColor[]]& /@ allPathsOut[g, 4]]
```

[image]

```
allPathsOut[g2, 4]
```

> {{4, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 10}}

```
HighlightGraph[g2, Style[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1], Opacity[1], 
  Arrowheads[.09],Thickness[.015], RandomColor[]]& /@ allPathsOut[g2, 4]]
```

[image]

**Timings:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
rg= RandomGraph[{10^4, 10^4}, DirectedEdges -> True];
allPathsOut[rg, 5] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0014

```
FindAllOutlet[rg, 5] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0478

```
allPathsOut[rg, 5] == FindAllOutlet[rg, 5]
```

> True

```
SeedRandom[12345]
rg = RandomGraph[{10^4, 10^4}, DirectedEdges->True];
v = RandomChoice[VertexList[rg]];
allPathsOut[rg, v] // RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 0.0043

```
FindAllOutlet[rg, v] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0704

```
FindAllOutlet[rg, v] == allPathsOut[rg, v]
```

> True